# CVMetalTextureCacheCreate & triple-buffering

Tags: avfoundation, metal

I am implementing a triple-buffering scheme for my Metal drawing situation based on the suggestions [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/MTLBestPracticesGuide/TripleBuffering.html).

It is working very well.  I am playing video clips and I'm triple-buffering `CVPixelBuffer` samples as they arrive from `AVPlayer` objects in `AVFoundation`. In the transition between videos, I have a single *pair* of such triple-buffer schemes in operation, and a kernel shader involved.  Seems to work well @ 60fps.

However, I have a question about the buffering requirements of **`CVMetalTextureCacheCreate`**.

I have also triple-buffered these caches (creating three such caches backing each movie), **but I'm not sure if I need to do so**.  I am utilizing the cache (with a call to `CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage`) in the `drawRect` method of the `MTKView`.  For a pair of movies, there'd be a pair of such calls to disparate caches.

Any suggestions in this regard would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to create 1 texture cache, the 1 cache corresponds to N textures.